# keyboard event foccussing on a particular window

Tags: c++, events, keyboard

I am working on using human gestures for game controlling.
I am trying to simulate key-press when a particular gesture is recognized.
i Am using keybd_event for this. But whats happening is the keys are getting simulated on a notepad file.
but when i try out on a game keys are not getting simulated.
what am i doing wrong??

keybd_event(0x41,0xb8,0 , 0); //a pressed
keybd_event(0x41,0x8f, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0); // a released